# Updating Scrapy Spider does not reflect changes

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I'm using **Scrapy 1.0.3** with **Python 2.7.6**. I've placed print statements in a file under the /spiders directory for debugging purposes. However, I've more recently added new print statements but scrapy isn't throwing it onto the console. Finding this suspicious, I removed the previous print statements to see if scrapy would update the output accordingly. However, the output from the previous working code still remains the same.

I'm suspecting that scrapy caches the working codes and found .Python to be a suspecting file which I've removed but the issue remains.

Some google-fu didn't help either and I was wondering if anyone could enlighten me if the issue lies with python or scrapy?

Comment: What if you would remove the `pyc` files in the project?

Comment: Thanks @alecxe! I removed the suspected .pyc files in the project and reran the spider and the changes are updated! However, I'm a little confused as to why python wouldn't reflect the changes in the existing .pyc files? Or could this be an error on scrapy's end?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @alecxe recommended in the comments, removing the .pyc files followed by re-running the `scrapy crawl crawler-name` recompiles the python code and creates the new, update .pyc files.